# Removing last node in a list error

Tags: c++, c++11

The purpose this code is to delete the last node in a list. This works but I get an error if I try to delete the last value in the list.

```
   bool LinkedList::removeBack()

 {

Node* temp2 = nullptr;
if(isEmpty())
{
    return false; // nothing to remove
}
else
{
    last=m_front; //starting at first node and pointing to second
    while(last->getNext()!=nullptr)     
    {
        temp2=last;         
        last=last->getNext(); //goes to end of list
    }       
    temp2->setNext(nullptr);    
    delete last; //deletes last object
    last=nullptr;//deletes the pointer
    m_size--; //reduces counter
    return true; 
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `delete`s when you're only removing one node?  Loop to the end, *Adjust the links appropriately*, and then delete the orphaned node.  Isn't that all you really need to do?

Comment: You're right and I have removed 'delete temp2' and extended the while loop. Thanks for responding so fast!

Answer (score 0):

Before your else add this code:

```
else if(m_front->getNext() == nullptr)
{
    m_front->setNext(nullptr); 
    return true;
} 
else ...
```